# Unable to compile Riak on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: amazon-s3, compiler-errors, raspberry-pi3, riak

currenty I'm trying  to install **Riak** on the **Raspberry Pi 3** for testing purposes. I used the following instruction from basho:

http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.2/setup/installing/source/

I'm having problems compiling it from source. I tried to compile it on **Raspbian Jessie** and then switched to **Ubuntu Server 16.04**. Both times with the same result. It is not compiling and aborts at a certain point. I don't know what causes the problem since it only says: `recipe for target 'util/perf_count.o' failed`. Searching Google and the mailing list from basho weren't successful.

The version of `gcc` is `gcc (Raspbian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2`. The version of `Erlang` is  `Erlang R16B02_basho8 (erts-5.10.3)`

The commands i used are the following:

**Installing Erlang:**

```
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.basho.com/erlang/otp_src_R16B02basho10.tar.gz

tar zxvf otp_src_R16B02-basho10.tar.gz

cd OTP_R16B02_basho10
./otp_build autoconf
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

**Installing Riak:**

```
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.basho.com/riak/2.2/2.2.1/riak-2.2.1.tar.gz

tar zxvf riak-2.2.1.tar.gz

cd riak-2.2.1
make locked-deps
make rel
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

### Output:

```
`./include/leveldb/atomics.h:155:15: note: 
template argument deduction/substitution failed util/perf_count.cc:439:40:
note: deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘ValueT’ 
(‘unsigned int’ and‘int’ add_and_fetch(ptr_32, 1);`


`Makefile:190: recipe for target 'util/perf_count.o' failed
make[1]: *** [util/perf_count.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Riak/riak/deps/eleveldb/c_src/leveldb'
ERROR: Command [compile] failed!
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make: *** [compile] Error 1`
```

Comment: Could you please expand your description to include every command you executed, including all `git` commands? Also, what is the version of Erlang and `gcc` that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

After digging deeper I got some help from Basho's mailing list (many thanks).
The Link below shows the steps to solve this problem:

http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2017-April/019187.html

The next link is a detailed instruction, which helps to install Riak on the Raspberry Pi 3:

http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.2/setup/installing/source/